# Execute a method when object is changed (OOP)

Tags: oop, object, variables, parameter-passing

I'm learning OOP and trying to write a simple program that will execute some method every time when a specific varible will change.
I have two classes:

```
public class SomeClass {

  private OtherClass object;

  public OtherClass getObject() {
    return this.object;
  }

  public void setObject(OtherClass object) {
    objectChanged();
    this.object = object;
  }

  private void objectChanged() {
    System.out.println("Object has changed");
  }
}


public class OtherClass {

  private int value = 5;

  public int getValue() {
    return this.value;
  }

  public void setValue(int value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
}
```

The variable objectChanged should be called every time when variable "object" is changed. My first naive idea was to put the method call inside of set function. But what if you change the object after you set it? Like this:

```
SomeClass someObject = new SomeClass();
OtherClass otherObject = new OtherClass();
someObject.setObject(otherObject); //"Object has changed"
otherObject.setValue(10); //nothing happens yet
```

I need someObject to realize that object stored inside of it changed its value to 10, but how do i do it? Is it even possible in OOP?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to be reasonable, but one should consider many things. This is why there is no automatic way to do it in general. It is not part of the OOP paradigm as such. If this would be some automatic behavior, it would cause huge overhead as it is not often needed to observe changes this way. But you can, of course, implement your way depending on your concrete requirements.

There are at least two approaches.

In MVVM (like WPF) there is an `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface (let's call it a pattern) you can use to trigger a notification yourself, mutch like you did with `SomeClass`. However when you are nesting objects, you need to wire up that mechanism.to cascade: you should do the same with `OtherClass` and also connect the actual instances to bubble up changes.
See: https://rehansaeed.com/tag/design-patterns/

An other option is the `Observable` pattern. Each time the object changes state, you emit an instance - the current instance. However, you should care to emit unmutable objects. At least by using an interface that makes it read-only. But you still need to wire up the object tree to react to the changes of nested objects.

If your platform supports reflection, and you create a proper toolset, you could make this wiring up quite simple. But again: this is not strictly related to the paradigm.